# Mssql setup on fedora linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, terminal, fedora-38

So I want to run mssql server on me fedora 38 (worksation), I have followed through the installation process on microsoft and all. I am done with the dependencies. but when i run the
   `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`
after i select the edition and the language i get this error.

```
onfiguring SQL Server...

This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Thu Oct 26 23:39:13 2023
The following diagnostic information is available:

         Reason: 0x00000007
         Status: 0xc0000022
        Message: Unable to set persistent hive root.
    Stack Trace:
                 file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000209BE2
                 file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000208E31
                 file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000284BC9
                 file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000020723A
                 file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000207454
                 file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000020627E
                 file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x00000000002050A6
                 file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000205539
                 file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x00000000003A0401
        Process: 5652 - sqlservr
         Thread: 5657 (application thread 0x8)
    Instance Id: 44fc8299-19f1-4688-b057-3c2ab7a796c0
       Crash Id: 3194e796-baf8-4d5d-ad0e-4db0e894112c
    Build stamp: 038b081ccf6cfd32a0abb8b6171cbb09f750a85940fa288744d29c4ebde01a69
   Distribution: Fedora Linux 38 (Workstation Edition)
     Processors: 4
   Total Memory: 8220528640 bytes
      Timestamp: Thu Oct 26 23:39:13 2023
     Last errno: 13
Last errno text: Permission denied
Capturing a dump of 5652
Successfully captured dump: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.10_26_2023_23_39_13.5652
Executing: /opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh with parameters
     handle-crash.sh
     /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
     5652
     /opt/mssql/bin
     /var/opt/mssql/log/
     
     44fc8299-19f1-4688-b057-3c2ab7a796c0
     3194e796-baf8-4d5d-ad0e-4db0e894112c
     
     /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.10_26_2023_23_39_13.5652

Fedora Linux 38 (Workstation Edition)
Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal', 'wheel' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal', 'wheel' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Thu 26 Oct 23:39:15 GMT 2023 Capturing program information
Dump already generated: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.10_26_2023_23_39_13.5652, moving to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.5652.temp/core.sqlservr.5652.gdmp
Moving logs to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.5652.temp/log/paldumper-debug.log
Thu 26 Oct 23:39:15 GMT 2023 Capturing program binaries
/usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/auditd’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/share/empty.sshd’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d’: Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/mssql/log/HkEngineEventFile_0_133428314715990000.xel': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/mssql/log/system_health_0_133428314745660000.xel': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/mssql/log/log_1.trc': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog.1': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/mssql/log/HkEngineEventFile_0_133428339571980000.xel': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/mssql/log/system_health_0_133428339597460000.xel': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/mssql/log/log_2.trc': Operation not permitted
Thu 26 Oct 23:39:16 GMT 2023 Compressing the dump files
Core dump and information are being compressed in the background. When
complete, they can be found in the following location:
  /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.10_26_2023_23_39_13.5652.tbz2
Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
took 24s
```

when i try starting the server by running
`sudo systemctl status mssql-server`
i get this error

```
 mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-10-26 23:29:15 GMT; 13min ago
   Duration: 6.301s
       Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
    Process: 3055 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3055 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 2min 36.855s

Oct 26 23:29:15 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit process 3052 (sh) remains running after unit stopped.
Oct 26 23:29:15 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit process 3053 (tar) remains running after unit stopped.
Oct 26 23:29:15 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit process 3054 (bzip2) remains running after unit stopped.
Oct 26 23:29:15 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit process 3604 (sh) remains running after unit stopped.
Oct 26 23:29:15 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit process 3605 (tar) remains running after unit stopped.
Oct 26 23:29:15 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit process 3606 (bzip2) remains running after unit stopped.
Oct 26 23:29:15 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
Oct 26 23:30:40 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 26 23:30:40 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 26 23:30:40 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

how do i fix this. I cannot establish a connection too

I have reinstalled all the packages again and tried different versions of mssql server. still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

to save me any further problems, I used the docker approach to install mssql and it works very fine.